# wan to loop tru and check date and copy VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My date is range from b1,c1,d1,e1.....etc etc i try to make a loop to check the date and copy the whole column of the current month but it dont work.. anyone can help?

```
Sub dat()
    Dim Lastcolumn As Long
    Dim Curcolumn As Long
    Dim NextDest As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("SHEET1")


    For Curcolumn = 2 To 10
        If IsDate(ws.Cells(Curcolumn, 1).Value) = True Then
            If Month(ws.Range("1" & Curcolumn).Value) = Month(Date) Then
                ws.Range("1" & Curcolumn & ":D" & CurRow).Copy
                NextDest = Sheets("SHEET2").Range("1s" & Column.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                Sheets("SHEET2").Range("1" & NextDest & ":D" & NextDest).PasteSpecial
                Else
            End If
        Else
            ws.Cells(1, Curcolumn).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next Curcolumn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code it is not picking up the cell that you're trying to refer.

```
 Sub dat()
    Dim Lastcolumn As Long
    Dim Curcolumn As Long
    Dim NextDest As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("SHEET1")


    For Curcolumn = 2 To 10
        If IsDate(ws.Cells(1, Curcolumn).Value) = True Then
            If Month(ws.Cells(1, Curcolumn).Value) = Month(Date) Then
                ws.Range(Cells(1, Curcolumn), Cells(CurRow, 4)).Copy
                NextDest = Sheets("SHEET2").Range("1s" & Column.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("SHEET2").Range(Cells(1, NextDest), Cells(NextDest, 4)).PasteSpecial
            Else
            End If
        Else
            ws.Cells(1, Curcolumn).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next Curcolumn
End Sub
```

Comment: it will not go into If IsDate(ws.Cells(Curcolumn, 1).Value) = True Then

Comment: It should be Cells(1,Curcolumn) since you are always checking first row.

Comment: Thanks, now it enter the if.. however it got error on ws.Range("1" & Curcolumn & ":D" & CurRow).Copy

Comment: @Sypnoticjr Not sure what is your range "1s" in sheet to but I have updated the other code in the answer.

Comment: NextDest = Sheets("SHEET2").Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                Sheets("SHEET2").Range(Cells(NextDest, 1), Cells(NextDest, 4)).PasteSpecial

Comment: It dont paste to the next column. it keep pasting over the data